# Is it appropriate, while initial screening, the HR asks about your age?

Tags: interviewing

I'd received a call from an HR of a consulting firm a couple of days back. Along with my current CTC, expected CTC, she also asked a question about my DOB. I'm a female.

I had never encountered such a question before, especially when it's the initial screening call.

What impression should I have of such a company? and If in case companies do ask a such question, what is the use of it?

Comment: Very important to know what country you are in.

Comment: Depending on the country they may have actually broken the law

Comment: @RichardTingle Not necessarily. Companies do need to check that you are of legal age and that, according to that country's laws, you can be employed.

Comment: What is a CTC ?

Comment: I put my DOB on my CV/resume. I'm in my 40s so if they're not going to hire me due to age discrimination it saves time all round.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is in the US, then they broke the law by asking this unless there is a job-specific reason they need this info (background check, etc.).  This law is in place to protect against age discrimination.

As far as what should you think, I wouldn't really worry about it unless you genuinely think they are discriminating against you.  The interviewer is probably inexperienced with what they can and can't ask.  That could be for any number of reasons, they could be new to the company, they perhaps weren't trained properly, or maybe the company is going through such a huge growth phase that they are having the intern interview candidates (I don't mean literally the intern, that's rhetorical).  Obviously the interview process isn't as organized as you'd like, but that often has little correlation to the work environment.

In the future, if they ask you a question like this, you've got two reasonable options:

1. Just answer it (you are doing nothing wrong if you're comfortable with this option) or
2. Politely say "I don't think you're supposed to ask me questions like that for equal employment opportunity reasons.  Did you have a reason you needed that info?"